# Light Probes Android not supported?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, light

I'm developing TD game for Android and in order to optimize it, I baked lightmaps and used Light Probes where dynamic objects (enemies) move. On PC, everything is working fine but when I run it on Android (GT-I9100), dynamic objects simply ignoring light probes..

I've attached screens, so you could see clear picture of the problem...
Thanks In Advance.

```
Light Probes Location http://tinypic.com?ref=302p3tf
```

[Image 2](http://tinypic.com?ref=f0nacz)

[Image 3](http://tinypic.com?ref=2v809cz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would Have to use Mobile Shaders or Other shaders that compliments Mobile. Shading prowess for Mobile is different from other platforms. Since Mobile Shaders pushes the limit of the mobile device, try to re consider using other shaders.

[Check this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irozI0kxyFc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have changes shaders on all dynamic objects to mobile ones... but the problem is still there :(

Comment: I started project from scratch.... It seems everything is ok.... and updated my Unity 4.6 to 5 :)